# Insert value into multiple locations in a list

Tags: beginner, haskell, linked-list, functional-programming

#### Code

```
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go _ [] = []
    go j (y:ys)
      | nextIndex `elem` indices = y : x : go (nextIndex + 1) ys
      | otherwise = y : go nextIndex ys
      where
        nextIndex = j + 1
```

#### Questions

1. How can I make this code more efficient?
2. How can I make the code easier to follow?
3. Is a recursive approach the correct one?
4. Do the Prelude or Data.List have any functions that could make this more readable/efficient?

Comment: If `indices` list might be large, consider using `Data.Set Int` instead of `[Int]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it intended that `insertAt 999 [1] [1..10]` inserts 999 at index 1, but `insertAt 999 [0] [1..10]` does nothing.  Shouldn't it insert a value at index 0?

Also, it looks like certain other insertions don't work correctly:

```
> insertAt 999 [2,5,6,7] [1..10]
[1,2,999,3,4,999,5,999,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Note that this inserts only at indices 2, 5, and 7 and appears to skip index 6.

My guess is that you probably wanted something more like:

```
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go _ [] = []
    go j (y:ys)
      | j `elem` indices = x : go (j+1) (y:ys)
      | otherwise        = y : go (j+1) ys
```

which handles these cases correctly:

```
λ> insertAt 999 [0] [1..10]
[999,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
λ> insertAt 999 [2,5,6,7] [1..10]
[1,2,999,3,4,999,999,999,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

It doesn't insert anything for `insertAt 999 [10] [1..10]`, but if you want that to insert at the end, then you need a slight modification:

```
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go j yall   | j `elem` indices =  x : go (j+1) yall
    go j (y:ys)                    =  y : go (j+1) ys
    go _ []                        = []
```

which works like so:

```
λ> insertAt 999 [0] [1..10]
[999,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
λ> insertAt 999 [2,5,6,7] [1..10]
[1,2,999,3,4,999,999,999,5,6,7,8,9,10]
λ> insertAt 999 [10] [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,999]
λ> insertAt 999 [10,11,12] [1..10]  -- multiple consecutive indices off the end
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,999,999,999]
```

I think this version is quite readable.  The main efficiency problem is that, if `indices` is more than a few elements, the repeated linear traversals of the `elem` function through the `indices` list will be slow.  A second efficiency problem is that if all the insertions are near the beginning, you will end up traversing the entire input list even after all the insertions have been performed.

You can improve the performance substantially by using an `IntSet`.  (A plain `Set` from `Data.Set` would work, too, but `IntSet`s are even faster for sets of `Int`s.)

```
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices = go 0
  where
    indices' = IntSet.fromList indices
    go j yall | j `IntSet.member` indices' =  x : go (j+1) yall
    go j (y:ys)                            =  y : go (j+1) ys
    go _ []                                = []
```

You could also pass the `IntSet` as a parameter to `go` and delete indices as they are used.  This might be faster, but you'd need to benchmark it to be sure:

```
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices = go 0 (IntSet.fromList indices)
  where
    go j indices' yall | j `IntSet.member` indices' =  x : go (j+1) (IntSet.delete j indices') yall
    go j indices' (y:ys)                            =  y : go (j+1) indices' ys
    go _ _ []                                       = []
```

This would also allow you to stop inserting when the list of indices is empty, but again, only benchmarking will tell whether or not this is faster:

```
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices = go 0 (IntSet.fromList indices)
  where
    go _ indices' yall | IntSet.null indices'       =  yall
    go j indices' yall | j `IntSet.member` indices' =  x : go (j+1) (IntSet.delete j indices') yall
    go j indices' (y:ys)                            =  y : go (j+1) indices' ys
    go _ _ []                                       = []
```

Personally, I think I probably would have approached it by writing a `go` function that operates on the current index and a **sorted** list of indices:

```
insertAt x indices = go 0 (sort indices)
```

This way, we can directly compare the current index with the **next** insertion point in the sorted list:

```
go j (i:is) (y:ys) | i == j = ...
```

This variant would look something like:

```
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices = go 0 (sort indices)
  where
    go _ []     yall              = yall
    go j (i:idxs) yall   | j == i = x : go (j+1) idxs yall
                         | j >  i = go j idxs yall -- delete duplicate indices
    go j idxs     (y:ys)          = y : go (j+1) is ys
    go _ _        []              = []
```

This avoids those efficiency problems I mentioned earlier without having to switch to a different data structure.  Sorting the index list and consuming it as insertions are made will avoid any traversals through the index list, since you're only ever looking at the list's head.  Also, when the index list is empty, the `go _ [] yall = yall` case will immediately return the remaining list without further processing.

I'm not sure that there's any clever, non-recursive method that uses folds or other functions from `Data.List` and ends up being better than the above.  You can replace the recursion with `unfoldr`.  For example, given the version from above:

```
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go j yall   | j `elem` indices =  x : go (j+1) yall
    go j (y:ys)                    =  y : go (j+1) ys
    go _ []                        = []
```

you can rewrite this as:

```
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices lst = unfoldr step (0, lst)
  where step (j, lst)  | j `elem` indices = Just (x, (j+1, lst))
        step (j, y:ys)                    = Just (y, (j+1, ys))
        step (_, [])                      = Nothing
```

and the other versions can be rewritten similarly.  This doesn't particularly improve readability, and I doubt it's more efficient.

Another completely different approach might be to `intercalate` the insertion value into a sequence of sublists generated from the indexes.  So, for example, given the indexes `[2,5,6,7]`, you might want to first break the input list `[1..10]` up into sublists between the insertions:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[],[],[5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

It might be easiest to first convert a sorted list of indices into a list of sizes for all the sublists except the last:

```
indicesToChunks :: [Int] -> [Int]
indicesToChunks indices = zipWith (\i j -> i-j-1) indices (-1 : indices)
```

giving:

```
> indicesToChunks [2,5,6,7]
[2,2,0,0]
```

and then write a function to break a list into sublists based on these sublist sizes.  It's pretty easy to write recursively:

```
chunks :: [Int] -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunks [] lst = [lst]
chunks (n:ns) lst = a : chunks ns b
  where (a,b) = splitAt n lst
```

Then, you can write:

```
insertAt :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt x indices = intercalate [x] . chunks (indicesToChunks (sortu indices))
  where -- unique elements in sorted order
        sortu = map head . group . sort
```

The definition of `sortu` is weird, but it's a reasonable method of sorting and removing duplicates.  (The `nub` function in `Data.List` removes duplicates, but doesn't do it efficiently for sorted lists, the way `map head . group` does.)

Note that this version behaves a little differently than the others, if there are insertions at the end of the list that skip indexes.  The earlier versions all insert only one `999` at the end of the list in this example:

```
> insertAt 999 [10,1000] [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,999]
```

treating the `1000` as an out-of-bounds index.  However, the `intercalate`-based version inserts two `999`s:

```
> insertAt 999 [10,1000] [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,999,999]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As arrowd said: your repeated linear elem call slows you down quadratically.
2. You can abstracize disassembly and assembly into separate functions:
3. The predefined helpers already encapsulate the needed standard recursions for you:
4. I found bitwise set logic useful as a speedup and groupBy fed with a scanl stairway:

```hs
import Data.Bits;import Data.Bool;import Data.Function;import Data.List
bitmapAt indices=foldl(.|.)0$map(2^)indices::Integer
groupsAt indices=scanl1(+)$map(signum.(.&.bitmapAt indices).(2^))[0..]
splitsAt indices=map(map snd).groupBy(on(==)fst).zip(groupsAt indices)
insertAt indices x xs=intercalate[x]$splitsAt indices xs
main=let indices=[5,4,4,3,5,6,7,4,3,2,0] in 
 print(bitmapAt indices,take 19$groupsAt indices,insertAt indices '#' ['a'..'z'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/tSsMwFP2fpwhYTILh0k2nOOkPhwiCb1AqxDarYWkSkhTq8N1rVoStlXAhnHPPx/0S4SC1HkfVOesjfhFRwE7F8DQDrNUz4LU3dVTWzMB3FSL6VLET7jliZRpVy1DsrW40hR9geZYYuv5gf9R2@2aibKVHrbe9CxeiUAujV/SGTZKgWtN3QOEalvYMToaszAEqFJxOzS9sTuI0OJiGwRSy@6bW0KJg@xAZHJWjy2yGlAnSxzOCBzyEQqWuvhZaRFkOVbbMSiuoE8oUWp7zyw2/S@@Wb/g9f5h@a55XiccIO58s6fIgHsVB4tVjtuzF/9UiVwSXRBAAciQVG8df)